# shell process creation error in system() command

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code in my c++ project:

```
std::string run_command = "build/executable input.txt";
std::string copy_command = "cp output.txt output_1.txt;";

int status1= system(run_command.c_str());
int status2=system(copy_command.c_str());
```

It perfectly runs in my pc, but doesn't work in my laptop. Both system calls return -1, meaning that there is a problem in shell process creation. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Are "build\executable" and "cp" available from the directory you run this program from?

Comment: do **build/executable** and **input.txt** exist?

Comment: yeah , sure they exist. I said they execute perfectly at my pc. and my laptop has the copy of the same files, forlders,etc.

Comment: is **build/executable** an executable? does it have the rights to be executet? is the current path right, while you running your program (see kol's comment)? what os? actually some more information could help a bit.

Comment: yeah the executable is an executable!  and I can run it directly from the terminal, and it has the rwx privileges for the group and r-x for the rest . I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I checked and found that the problem is not with the above commands, even the system("ls") returns -1. Do you have any comments about that?

Comment: what is the return value of `system()`?

Comment: Has the laptop linux s.o.?

Comment: i said the return value is -1 for all calls.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by [**manual**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system):

> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise. This latter return status is
>   in the format specified in wait(2). Thus, the exit code of the command
>   will be WEXITSTATUS(status). In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
>   the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

So, path should be correct. Try to add some print debug in your scripts.
Maybe you are referring to resources or libraries that in your laptop does not exist.

Comment: I checked and found that the problem is not with the above commands, even the system("ls") returns -1. Do you have any comments about that?

Answer (score 0):

try using ptrace and print errno (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to find the reason as to why system call failed. This is another resource to steer you on why the system call failed http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/217348-get-system-error-message

P.S.
I'm not entirely confident in writing c++ systems programs but i build a shell in C and printing errno helps. I definitely recommend using ptrace as well as monitoring whether the OS has enough resource to allocate new processes.